# Breaking while loop into months?

Tags: php

I'm using a while loop so it loops trough 01 January to 31 December.
As you can imagine, this is a long list, my solution would be to break it into multiple columns or using jquery accordion so you can easily open it by month.

Sofar i have:

```
$year_selected = date("Y");
$startdatum = "00-01-$jaar_selected";
$einddatum = "30-12-$jaar_selected";

while (strtotime($startdatum) <= strtotime($einddatum)) { 

    $startdatum = date ("d-m-Y", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($startdatum)));
    $weekday = strftime("%d-%m-%y %A", strtotime($startdatum));

    if(in_array($startdatum, $dagen_new)) {
         echo "<input checked type='checkbox' name='$startdatum' value='$startdatum'>
         <label $red>$weekday</label>";
    } else {
         echo "<input type='checkbox' name='$startdatum' value='$startdatum'>
         <label $red>$weekday</label>";
    }   
}
```

What i need is that you get the dates of the month, so 1-31 for example. Like i have now but it's a long list... You can check the date, which im putting in a database, so if do something on the front-end at the date you selected here, you get an error. But since it's a long list now, i would like it to break into multiple columns or stuff, so you won't have to scroll for ages.

Does anyone has an solution for this, could it be relatively easy to adapt?

Comment: It would help (for readability purposes) if you indented your code appropriately.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish. How do you intend to use the dates that you generate?

Comment: Will indent again and remove some unwanted stuff for you guys,

What i need is that you get the dates of the month, so 1-31 for example.
Like i have now but it's a long list...

You can check the date, which im putting in a database, so if do something on the front-end at the date you selected here, you get an error.

But since it's a long list now, i would like it to break into multiple columns or stuff, so you won't have to scroll for ages.

Comment: Do you want to group your input fields by month?

Comment: Inputfields should be for every day, just that for readability of the client, that he can quickly see the start of the month, just group the months but input fields has to remain as they are now.

So u would get something like a calender but then an overview in 1 year.

Comment: You can get month number for a given date by using date_parse_from_format [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php); `code` $d = date_parse_from_format("d-m-Y", $startdatum);
$month = $d["month"];

Comment: Managed it by implenting an array, using a for that obviously counts from 1 till 12.